# Back up failed error in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 18.04 following instructions as it appeared on the screen.

I am facing a back-up failure with the following error.

```
Error processing remote manifest (duplicity-inc.20180923T095052Z.to.20180927T050242Z.manifest.gpg): GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: WARNING: "--no-use-agent" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg: starting migration from earlier GnuPG versions
gpg: porting secret keys from '/home/abhilash/.gnupg/secring.gpg' to gpg-agent
gpg: can't open '/home/abhilash/.gnupg/secring.gpg': Permission denied
gpg: AES encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

Comment: Hi, I am still looking for an answer to this. I have no idea why this is happening. Is there any other back-up tool I can try?

Answer (score -1):

So, I have managed to fix this issue, where the backups procedure cannot look at your local files in gnupg, due to read rights. You need to change these rights, per the following post.

https://superuser.com/questions/954509/what-are-the-correct-permissions-for-the-gnupg-enclosing-folder-gpg-warning

I had to use 'sudo' in order to be allowed to do this by my installation. Then there are the two other commands:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.gnupg/
find ~/.gnupg -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find ~/.gnupg -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```

I wrote my backup to a new folder on my external drive.

Comment: add this comment to an answer, as it belongs to it